# Is it possible to use encrypted fields in filter criteria in list views and reports with shield platform after winter'17 release

Tags: platform-encryption, criteria-filter

In earlier versions, using encrypted fields in filter criteria in list views, reports and communities were not allowed.

I want to know if encrypted fields in filter criteria are now available in **list views, reports and communities**.

Comment: The most recent release was Spring 17. And do you have some reason to believe things have changed?

Answer (score 2):

We are actively working on it, we can't give any timeline yet though.